# Android app Null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

i am trying to build a newbie app which drop an array of pizza topic from the top of the screen and the user is supposed to avoid them, but for some reason I'm getting NullPointerException in the logcat and the app crashes..
it says it happens in the firstSet() when i'm trying to put value in the point.y which make no sense because i'm initializing them in the constractor.

```
package com.example.secondapp;

import java.util.Random;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.View;

public class EnemyTopics extends View {
private Drawable[] topic;
private Point[] cords;
private int width,height,screenHgt,screenWid,ClosestTopic,score;
private int tomatos,olives,mushroom,onion;
private UserCharacter character;
private Context context;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public EnemyTopics(Context context,int wid,int hgt,int screenHgt,int screenWid,UserCharacter uc) {
    super(context);
    this.cords = new Point[20];
    for(Point point : cords) {
        point = new Point();
        point.x = 0;
        point.y = 0;
    }           
    this.width = wid;
    this.height = hgt;
    this.topic = new Drawable[20];
    this.tomatos = R.drawable.tomatos;
    this.olives = R.drawable.olives;
    this.mushroom = R.drawable.mushroom;
    this.onion = R.drawable.onion;
    this.ClosestTopic = 0;
    this.screenHgt = screenHgt;
    this.screenWid = screenWid;
    this.character = uc;
    this.score = 0;
    this.context = context;
    this.firstSet();
    this.setBounds();
}

public int maxLeft(int position) {
    return this.cords[position].x - (this.width/2);
}
public int maxRight(int position) {
    return this.cords[position].x + (this.width/2);
}
public int maxTop(int position) {
    return this.cords[position].y - (this.height/2);
}
public int maxBottom(int position) {
    return this.cords[position].y + (this.height/2);
}
public void setBounds() {
    int pos = 0;
    for (Drawable topics : this.topic) {
        topics.setBounds(maxLeft(pos), maxTop(pos), maxRight(pos), maxBottom(pos));
        pos++;
    }
}
public void moveTopics() {
    int pos = 0;
    for (Point p : this.cords) {
        if(maxBottom(pos) <= screenHgt) {
            p.y++;
        }
        else {
            p.y = -200;
        }
        pos++;
    }
    if(maxTop(ClosestTopic) > character.maxBottom()) {
        ClosestTopic++;
        score++;
    }
    if(ClosestTopic <= 19)
        ClosestTopic = 0;
}
public void checkHit() {
    if(maxBottom(ClosestTopic) >= character.maxTop() && maxTop(ClosestTopic) <= character.maxBottom() && maxLeft(ClosestTopic) <= character.maxRight() && maxRight(ClosestTopic) >= character.maxLeft()) {
        score = 0;
        this.firstSet();
        character.restart();
    }
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void firstSet() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int random = r.nextInt(4);
    int pos = 0;
    for (Point p : cords) {
        p.y = (0 - pos*15);
        p.x = screenWid/2;
        switch (random) {
        case 0:
            topic[pos]= context.getResources().getDrawable(tomatos,null);   
            break;
        case 1:
            topic[pos]= context.getResources().getDrawable(olives,null);    
            break;
        case 2:
            topic[pos]= context.getResources().getDrawable(mushroom,null);  
            break;
        case 3:
            topic[pos]= context.getResources().getDrawable(onion,null); 
            break;
        default:
            topic[pos]= context.getResources().getDrawable(tomatos,null);   
        }
        pos++;
        random = r.nextInt(4);
    }
}
public void draw (Canvas canvas) {
    for (Drawable topics : this.topic) {
        topics.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

}

i disabled the thread that moves them, which means the problem is either on the constructor,firstSet or setBound but i cant find it, so i'll appriciate help:)
thanks in advance.

```
logcat:
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): Process: com.example.secondapp, PID: 1154
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.secondapp/com.example.secondapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.Point.y' on a null object reference
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.Point.y' on a null object reference
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.example.secondapp.EnemyTopics.firstSet(EnemyTopics.java:96)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.example.secondapp.EnemyTopics.<init>(EnemyTopics.java:42)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at com.example.secondapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
09-20 14:13:53.725: E/AndroidRuntime(1154):     ... 9 more
```

Comment: post your stack trace here which you get in logcat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot assign objects to an array using this kind of loop. `point` is a copy of the reference, and it is not copied back into the array.

```
this.cords = new Point[20];
for(Point point : cords) {
    point = new Point();  
    point.x = 0;
    point.y = 0;
}
```

Use the "old-fashioned" way:

```
this.cords = new Point[20];
for(int i = 0; i < cords.length; ++i ) {
    cords[i] = new Point();  
    cords[i].x = 0;
    cords[i].y = 0;
}
```